# Entropy of SIM PIN code

Tags: entropy

Each mobile SIM card has a four-digit number ($b_1$,$b_2$,$b_3$,$b_4$) called PIN code. Each digit $0 \le b_i \le 9$ (for i = 1, 2, 3, 4) is generated using a random 16-bit sequence as follows:
$b_i=(r_{4i-3} + r_{4i-2} .2 + r_{4i-1}.2^2 + r_{4i}.2^3)\pmod {10} $.
How we can calculate the antropy of PIN code? I know the entropy relation but I have no view.

Comment: Clearly HW, What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm calling here $B_1, B_2, B_3, B_4$ the four random variables representing the four digits (I do not like to call a variable $p$).
It seems a good idea to compute the entropy of only $1$ digits, and then because the four digits are independently chosen, we could multiply this number by $4$.
Let $q_i= \mathbb{P}(B_1 = i)$ for any $i \in\{0, \dots, 9\}$.
$$H(B_1)= -\sum_{i=0}^9 q_i\log(q_i)$$.

You can notice for $0\leq j \leq 5$, $q_j =\frac{2}{16}$, and for $6\leq j\leq9$, $q_j= \frac{1}{16}$.
Then, because $\log_2(\frac{2}{16})= (1-4)$, and  $\log_2(\frac{1}{16})= (-4)$.
\begin{align}
H(B_1)&= -\left(6\cdot \frac{2}{16}(1-4) + 4\cdot \frac{1}{16}(-4)\right) \\
&=\frac{9+4}{4}= \frac{13}{4} = 3.25
\end{align}

After multiplying by $4$, because there is $4$ digits (as I've said before), we obtain $13$ bits of entropy.

Comment: Just looking at this. Are you convinced that $p_i$ is smooth and continuous? There are no gaps? And are they IID; they come from a formula...

Comment: I've deleted one sentence does it make more sense for you?

Comment: Oh I'm not criticising. I'm suspicious of the formulation of $p_i$. I am of all constructs that have implications for the security services. Four truly random digits have H = 13.3 bits ($\log_2(10) \times 4$). Seed $r$ is 16 bits. 16 > 13.3, so why not directly use $r$ and rejection sample down? It whiffs.

Comment: Nobody generates such probabilistic random pins. HW.

Comment: Since this is homework, I will let it to the OP to fix a slight error.

Comment: I've corrected the error...

Comment: Still, there is a mistake from first-class of rational numbers.

Comment: Dear Paul Uszak, thank you for your consideration. Yes, this scheme in comparison to a four-digit random number  is some unreasonable, but the purpose was comparison of the entropy of two designs.

Comment: Dear levgeni, I was very thankful you are considering my problem.

Comment: For comparison: a uniformly random 10-digit PIN has ≈13.2877 bit of entropy, and generating the PIN by reducing the 16-bit value modulo 10000 yields ≈13.2835 bit of entropy.

Comment: I repeat: are these values independently distributed? If not, the entropy will be (much) lower. Some Python is required.

Answer (score 0):

For $0 \le b_i \le 5$, $p_i=\frac{2}{16}$ and for $6 \le b_i \le 9$, $p_i=\frac{1}{16}$. Then we calculate the logarithm values, which are respectively equal to $\log_2(\frac{2}{16})=(1-4)$ and $\log_2(\frac{1}{16})=(-4)$. Now, according to the entropy relation,
\begin{align}
  \ H(b_1) &= -\ \sum_{i=0}^{9} p_i \log_2(p_i ),
\end{align}
we will have:

\begin{align}
  \ H(b_1) &= \ -(6 \cdot \frac{2}{16}(1-4) + 4 \cdot \frac{1}{16}(-4))=3.25,
\end{align}
which is the entopy of one digit. As there are four independent digits, multiply the value by 4 and we get 13 bits of entropy.

Comment: Watch the sign, and the exclusion of indices $j$ with zero probability. It's $H(b_1)=\displaystyle\sum_{j=0\ldots9\text{ and }p_j>0}p_j \log_2(1/p_j)$ or equivalently $H(b_1)=-\displaystyle\sum_{j=0\ldots9\text{ and }p_j>0}p_j \log_2(1/p_j)$.

Comment: @fgrieu on the right, do you mean $\log_2(p_j)$? This comment shouts: delete me if I'm correct.